# Change calendar month Programmatically in Material UI

Tags: css, reactjs, datepicker, material-ui

I am using Material UI DatePickers https://material-ui-pickers.dev/demo/datepicker, I have two DatePickers From and To. what I want to achieve is when I change the month of From DatePicker then it should also change the month of To DatePicker. But I want only Month to change in TO DatePicker, date should remain unselected in DatePicker. Thanks in advance for help,
below is my Html

```
      onChange = (newDate) => { setEndDate(newDate); }

      <DatePicker
        disableToolbar
        variant="inline"
        label="Only calendar"
        helperText="No year selection"
        value={startDate}
        onMonthChanged={onChange}
      />

       <DatePicker
        disableToolbar
        variant="inline"
        label="Only calendar"
        helperText="No year selection"
        value={endDate}
      />
```

I have called the above function onChange on onMonthChange() and inside it I am setting the end date which is TO Date, months gets changed but date also remains selected. how to only set month??

Comment: Suggestion: When i read your question, I wanted to see your code or just try what you telling. So showing us your structure or prepare a snippet can be very helpful I think.

Comment: i have updated, on onMonthChange()  i am setting the end date, it changes the month but i don't want date to be selected, only month should change.Thanks for replying

Comment: You can use `minDate` prop of datepicker maybe?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?